# Mongo query multiple collections to have one cursor with documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, cursor, driver

Good day for everybody!

I'm new one in mongo and I need your help guys. Let me explain what I have and what I want to do.

In my database I have multiple collections  like:

```
Collection name: Collection1

 _id : XXX

 StringField : name1

 IntegerField : 1

Collection name: Collection2

 _id : YYY

 StringField : name2

 IntegerField : 2

Collection name: Collection3

 _id : ZZZ

 StringField : name3

 IntegerField : 3
```

e.t.c.

All what i want to do is to return the one cursor with all documents which taken from collections by some filter.

```
var filters = new List<FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>>();

foreach (var collection in Collections)
{
 var bsonFilter = BuildDocumentFilter(); //Return type is FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>
 filters.Add(bsonFilter);
 var findfluent = collection.Find(bsonFilter);  
 var cursor = findfluent.ToCursor();   
}
```

As you see here I'm stucked.. We have for earch collection his own cursor but I need to query collections to retrieve documents and to put it in one cursor.

Thank you for your help guys! If something is not clear, tell me I'll try to explain more detailed.

Comment: This doesnt look like a good design.  If you did what you want to do you'd have a cursor containing a mix of documents from different collections, which might have different schema.  Why do you want to create a cursor like this?  Why not just create a different cursor for each collection?

Comment: Structure of those collections are the same..

>> Why not just create a different cursor for each collection?

Because till the end I want to have something like


[code] while (cursor.MoveNext())
{
 var documentsFromDifferentCollections = cursor.Current
}[/code]

Comment: `while (cursor.MoveNext())

{
   
  var documentsFromDifferentCollections = cursor.Current

}`